# Guzzle: Uncaught exception & memory leak

Tags: php, exception, curl, memory-leaks, guzzle

I'm having weird issues while using [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

When I try to simulate an erroneous request (e.g. a request which returns a status code 404) Guzzle throws a ClientException containing all the details of why that request failed.

When I try to catch this exception my script exits with a fatal error stating that I didn't catch the exception and it shows an XDebug trace stating that I had a memory leak somehow.

My code looks like this:
**Note:** httpClient is a valid instance of GuzzleHttp/CLient.

```
$request  = $this->httpClient->createRequest(
    'GET',
    '/templates/'.$id
);

try {
    $response = $this->httpClient->send($request);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    die('exception occured');
}
```

The error I end up with is the following:
**Guzzle stack trace**
[image: Guzzle stack trace]
**Memory leak**
[image: Memory leak]

Does someone have a suggestion to what might cause this uncaught exception + leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **XDebug** wants to consume more memory than the defined limit

Your limit is : **512MO** for A Script
Your **XDebug** wants to consume : **652MO**

You have 2 solutions to resolve this technical issue 
1 - Update your **php.ini** => `memory_limit = 768M` and after that restart your server
2 - In your **PHP** script put this line code on top :

```
ini_set("memory_limit","768M");
```

Now you must be completely sure that this memory leak will not happend in your production environment, by disabling **XDebug**

Comment: @HalayemAnis how did you discover this?