# Php Fatal error: momory size exhausted when using composer to install user-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

When triing to install FOSuserbundle with composer I got the following message in the Terminal:
 **"PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes) in phar:///Users/myname/MyWebSite/composer.phar/src/Composer/ DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 177"**

How can I fix it?

---

EDIT / FURTHER INFORMATION

In Terminal typing: **php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"**
get me the following: **128M**
while php.ini (App/MAMP/conf/php5.4.4/php.ini) has the following line:     **memory_limit = 32M**

why different value? 
how can I change the value so that composer can install the bundle?

I tried the following in terminal but got an error: **php -d memory_limit=512M composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php**
error ==> **Could not open input file: composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php**

Comment: Have a look at this https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md

Comment: composer is an _archive_, not just a file, its a self contained application, written in PHP, contained in a phar archive (cf [the PHAR extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php))

Comment: @ Bulk. I tried the following line (see also my Edit in main question) **php -d memory_limit=512M composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php** but this is not working. how can I change the memory_limit? which value should I set 512M?

Comment: i have already answered to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/28068875/4098311

Comment: I change php.ini memory_limit from 32M to 42M and got the same message when updating composer.phar in terminal.

Comment: Dont't forget to alter the variables in the CLI folder, that's what symfony uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this in the past by using simply:

```
php -d memory_limit=1G /usr/local/bin/composer update --prefer-dist --no-dev
```

Where the no-dev may help reduce the memory footprint too - certainly speed.

Answer (score 0):

Composer should be run with at least 1 GB of allowed and available memory. If your machine has less memory physically installed, you should consider upgrading or using a different machine - otherwise the process will start swapping and taking huge amounts of time, so something that should be done in less than a minute will take days.

If you are unable to raise the memory limit for PHP, you are out of luck unfortunately. Composer needs some huge data structures when updating.